# Bat file that alters specific xml element optimization

Tags: xml, batch-file, config

I have a batch script that updates a httpTransport element to httpsTransport for a specific binding name, in my case: CustomBinaryBinding.
How can I write it in a more elegant and efficient way.

bat file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set "search=httpTransport"
set "replace=httpsTransport"
set "bindingName=CustomBinaryBinding"
set INTEXTFILE=C:\Users\tudor\Desktop\batch\web.config
set OUTTEXTFILE=C:\Users\tudor\Desktop\batch\webTemp.config    
echo start
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (!INTEXTFILE!) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    for /f tokens^=1^,2^,3^ delims^=^<^"^= %%a in ("%%i") do (  
        if "%%b" equ "binding name" if "%%c" equ "CustomBinaryBinding" (
            set "insideCorrectBinding=y"
            )                              
        for /f "delims= " %%m in ("%%b") do (
            if "%%m" equ "httpTransport" (              
            set "onCorrectLine=y"                                                                               
            )
        )
    )
    if !insideCorrectBinding! equ y if !onCorrectLine! equ y (
        set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"  
        set "onCorrectLine="      
        set "insideCorrectBinding="
    )            
    echo(!line!                 
    )
)>"%OUTTEXTFILE%"
```

web.config:

```
<configuration>          
    <system.serviceModel>          
        <bindings>          
            <customBinding>          
                <binding name="CustomBinaryBinding">          
                  <binaryMessageEncoding />          
                  <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />          
                </binding>          
            </customBinding>      
            <customBinding>          
                <binding name="CustomBinaryBinding2">          
                  <binaryMessageEncoding />          
                  <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />          
                </binding>          
            </customBinding>                
        </bindings>          
        <client>          
          <endpoint address="../../PlatformAdminUtil.svc"          
               binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinaryBinding"          
               contract="PlatformAdminUtil.PlatformAdminUtil" name="CustomBinding_PlatformAdminUtil" />          
          <endpoint address="../../EntityAccess.svc"          
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinaryBinding"          
                contract="PlatformEntityAccess.EntityAccess" name="CustomBinding_EntityAccess" />          
          <endpoint address="../../EntityAdminAccess.svc"          
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinaryBinding"          
                contract="PlatformEntityAdminAccess.EntityAdminAccess" name="CustomBinding_EntityAdminAccess" />          
          <endpoint address="../../LogErrorService.svc"          
               binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinaryBinding"          
               contract="LoggerService.LogErrorService" name="CustomBinding_LogErrorService" />          
        </client>          
    </system.serviceModel>          
</configuration>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. What do you think is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

```
if !insideCorrectBinding! equ y if !onCorrectLine! equ y (
```

should be

```
if defined insideCorrectBinding if  defined onCorrectLine (
```

If these are **not** set then the code is interpreted as

```
if equ y if equ y (
```

which should generate an error.

Since these variables can only be set to *nothing* or `y`, then `if defined` is an appropriate query mechanism